# How to use the HTML Template In Xcode?

Tags: iphone

can some one tell me how i can use html template on the View Control?

Comment: What HTML template? I've never heard of it.

Comment: template means it's css file or can say classes and images both which's used in HTML form

Answer (score 0):

if you want to use existing html page you have then you should use ---

```
NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"MyWebPage" ofType:@"html"];
        NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:path];
        NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
    [myWebView loadRequest:request];
```

**OR**
If you want to use your own code for html then you can use

```
[myWebView loadHTMLString:@"<html><head></head><body style=\"font-family: sans-serif;\"> .... </body></html>" baseURL:nil];
```

Hope you were helped....